# How to hide button OnClick when saving a pdf in react using jsPDF?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, hide, jspdf

When I download my PDF it saves with the button that says print information in the PDF. The problem is I only want the div with the "content" ID to show.

Ive tried a few functions in the print function to hide my button but nothing has worked.

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
            import jsPDF from "jspdf";


            class MasterForm extends React.Component {
                constructor(props) {
                    super(props)
                    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                    this.state = {
                        firstname: '',
                        lastname: '',
                        address: '',
                        secondaddress: '',
                        city: '',
                        state: '',
                        zip: '',
                    }


                }

            handleChange = event => {
                    const {name, value} = event.target
                    this.setState({
                        [name]: value
                    })
                }


            print = () => {
                        const string = renderToString(<MasterForm />);
                        const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
                        pdf.fromHTML(string);
                        pdf.save("Print");
                    }


                    render() {
                        return (

            <React.Fragment>

            <div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <div id="content">
                                    <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none' }}>
                                        <li> {props.firstname} </li>
                                        <li> {props.lastname} </li>
                                        <li> {props.address} </li>
                                        <li> {props.secondaddress} </li>
                                        <li> {props.city}, {props.state} {props.zip} </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <br></br>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                            <button onClick={print} className="btn btn-success btn-block">Print Information</button>

                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                }

            ReactDOM.render(<MasterForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I expect the content ID dive to save in the PDF but instead I get the entire page, including the button.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it wouldn't print? There is no logic to remove it or not. You render the whole component when you print and when you display.

Passing a props to do the logics is one way of getting around that.

```
print = () => {
    const string = renderToString(<MasterForm />);
    const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
    pdf.fromHTML(string);
    pdf.save("Print");
}

{...}
{this.props.withButton
? <button onClick={print} className="btn btn-success btn-block">Print Information</button> 
: ''}
{...}

ReactDOM.render(<MasterForm withButton />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Hi Kerry, thanks for your help on this. The button is now hidden but I need it to show so I can click it then I need it to be hidden when the pdf is saved. Can you help?

Comment: @3rdisupreme sure. Did you follow what I wrote? It should show because of the props withButton is set to true in the render